# importing csv file to database using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I have created the following php code to import .csv file into mysql database running on phpmyadmin. The code is as follows:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pwd = '';

$database = 'mydatabase';
$table = 'demo';

if (!@mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
         $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
         echo 'upload file name: '.$fname.' ';
         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

         if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
         {

             $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
             $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

             while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
                $sql = "INSERT into demo(orders,quantity,country,dates,comment) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]', '$data[3]','$data[4]')";
                mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
             }

             fclose($handle);
             echo "Successfully Imported";

         }
         else
         {
             echo "Invalid File";
         }   
    }

    ?>
    <h1>Import CSV file</h1>
    <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Import File : <input type='file' name='sel_file' size='20'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
```

Once I submit the .csv file, it shows the message"imported successfully" however when I  check the database only the first row in the .csv file is imported to database. Other records are not.

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and it will not work anymore, use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `mysqli` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: Also, have a look at load data infile. It's way faster for importing csv

Comment: So i should replace the mysql, with mysqli in the code?

Comment: <h1>your code so good</h1>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com " >Jagdish dhakad</a>

Answer (score 0):

Don use `mysql_` change it to PDO or mysqli. That being said I've changed your code to explode each row and then assing the values to a list. It worked for me.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
    echo 'upload file name: '.$fname.' ';

    $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

    if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
    {
        foreach (file($fname) as $row)
        {
            list($data0, $data1, $data2, $data3, $data4) = explode(",", $row);
            $sql = "INSERT into demo(orders,quantity,country,dates,comment) values('$data0','$data1','$data2', '$data3','$data4')";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        echo "Successfully Imported";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid File";
    }   
}
```